# Google Cloud Code VSCode extension fills out my root drive

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-code

This is my first post in stack overflow.
I am using Arch Linux updated to the latest updates available for all packages.
My system is divided to 2 volumes: 30 GB for root folder and another volume for everything else.

I started using the google-cloud-code VSCode extension and I noticed that every time I create a version locally for cloud run my space on the root volume is getting smaller.

I don't know where are the files that cause that but now my root medium is 100% full and I can't create new deployments.

I suspect it is something in the python installation folder inside `/lib` and `/lib64` since both are on 4GB right now.
When checking the files sized with the `du -a` command I found out that the `./python3.9/site-packages/grpc` is the biggest with 9984 as the number represents the size (not sure what that means, mb maybe?) the next file the the list is 996 in size.
Please help me clear the space and please help me make it work without saving all of that data or at least not put it in the root volume

Thank you!

Comment: Could you update your question to provide some additional context about your project (do you have your own existing code base? Are you using one of the Cloud Code Samples? If so, which one?)

Please also specify which actions you are taking in VS Code to run locally. If you are able to safely clear out space on your root drive, it would also be helpful to see the output of `df -h` before and after running the commands in VS Code.

Comment: Hello! thank you for answering.
I am working for a company hence the code is a service I am writing that should be deployed to cloud run.
I am running the command ```Run on cloud run emulator``` which is available after installing the extension and clicking ``` CTRL+SHIFT+P```.
When I first got that message I checked and saw that the biggest folder is the cache folder from pacman and I used the paccache command and cleared few GB because I didn't know its the cloud code fault, after I used it again, it was full again but I don't have any more space to free but I'll try.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I found out what was the problem.
The cloud code created a volume for the deployment in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/NAME_OF_THE_DEPLOYMENT`
This volume is the storage of the container and it weigh a lot, I removed that from there for some free space and it worked.
Now for next deployment I need to change the default volume location or move the docker install location to be in the home dir.

Here is a [guide](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/z-logdata-analytics/5.1.0?topic=compose-relocating-docker-root-directory) I found:
Relocating the Docker Root directory
If the file space in the Docker Root directory is not adequate, you must relocate Docker Root.

Procedure
To relocate the Docker Root directory, complete the following steps as root or a user with “sudo all” authority:

Stop the Docker services:

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo systemctl stop docker.socket
sudo systemctl stop containerd
```

Create the necessary directory structure into which to move Docker Root by running the following command. This directory structure must reside on a file system with at least 50GB free disk space. Significantly more disk space may be required depending on your daily ingestion volumes and data retention policy:

`sudo mkdir -p /new_dir_structure`

Move Docker Root to the new directory structure:

`sudo mv /var/lib/docker /new_dir_structure`

Edit the file /etc/docker/daemon.json. If the file does not exist, create the file by running the following command:

`sudo vim /etc/docker/daemon.json`

Add the following information to this file:

```
{
  "data-root": "/new_dir_structure/docker”
}
```

After the /etc/docker/daemon.json file is saved and closed, restart the Docker services:

`sudo systemctl start docker`

Run the command:

`docker volume inspect NAME_OF_YOUR_VOLUME`

and make sure the mount point is the new path.

Name of your volume can be obtain using:

`docker volume ls`

Hope it will help other people here.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn off the Automatic installation of [dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/install#custom_versions_of_dependencies). Cloud Code VSCode installs minikube, gcloud, skaffold and a bunch of other stuff. If you don't need these you can turn them off

Comment: But why would it weigh so much and why would it install it again and again everytime it creates the container?

Comment: Well the files for these dependencies are big. If you turn them off they should be uninstalled.

Comment: I would not recommend doing this -- all it means is that you will need to manually install those dependencies if/when you need to use them (and in the case of running on Cloud Run Emulator as OP mentioned, all of these dependencies are necessary)